# addClass to elements on re-directed page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, redirect

I have page 1 (private) , page 2 (retirement) and page 3 (info). Page 1 and 2 both have sets of links that direct to page 3. On page 3 I have a vertical nav using affix/scroll spy.

depending on which page (1 or 2) directs to page 3, I want the  nav a active states to be a particular colour.

So page 1 has links such as:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-list private">
      <li><a href="useful-information.php?type=private#how" >How Right to Manage works</a></li>
      <li><a href="useful-information.php?type=private#qualify" >Do you qualify</a></li>
      ........
    </ul>
```

Page 2 has links such as:

```
     <ul class="nav nav-list retirement">
      <li><a href="useful-information.php?type=retirement#how" >How Right to Manage works</a></li>
      <li><a href="useful-information.php?type=retirement#qualify" >Do you qualify</a></li>
     ...........
    </ul>
```

On page 3 I have the affix/scrollSpy nav such as:

```
 <nav class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs" id="sub-nav">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="300">
    <li><a href="#how">How Right to Manage works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#qualify">Do you qualify</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rtm-process">The Right to Manage process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#selection-process">Management Selection Process</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="#fees">Fees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about-leasehold">About leasehold</a></li>
    <li><a href="#faq">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

So in theory, if you are directed to page 3 from page 1 (private) I want the active states on the affix/scrollspy nav to be *BLUE*. And if you directed to page 3 from page 2 (retirement) I want the active states on the affix/scrollspy nav to be *GREEN*

So I have these two styles that I would like to use for the addClass function:

```
#sub-nav .nav-pills .active a.ret,
#sub-nav .nav-pills .active a.ret:hover
{
background-color: #04A219; /* GREEN */
}
#sub-nav .nav-pills .active a.pri,
#sub-nav .nav-pills .active a.pri:hover
{
background-color: #086BE4; /* BLUE */
}
```

I have seen similar problems being answered on Stack' using jQuery but I have not been able to apply anything to my problem successfully. I think I am correct in saying a simple addClass can not be applied to a redirected page, but there are workarounds. So an insight to this would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `referrer` to see where you came from:-

```
var stateClass = document.referrer.indexOf('page-1-url') > -1 ? "pri" : "ret";
$('#sub-nav .nav-pills .active a').addClass(stateClass);
```